# How to trigger app function with specific time in Android?

Tags: android

I have create an app, and I set a datetime value, when hits the datetime value, the app will trigger the function on Android phone background. Any idea?

Comment: use alarmservice to achieve

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup the Alarm and Receiver for it.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

For example:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 1):

Good answers from @jcage and @goodm.
Just a hint: Don't forget to reset Alarm at device boot via a `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver in manifest. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED